# Negative Shannon Entropy

Tags: python, pandas, finance, entropy, yfinance

I have written a short code to calculate the log returns of a stock and the shannon entropy of the data. However, I am getting negative values for shannon entropy, which is terribly weird. I am using S=-plogp. Is it a problem with p not being discrete intervals? How could I divide p into intervals such that the entropy is calculated as S = - SUM_k(pklogpk)?

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm


plot_lreturnshist = False
plot_lreturns = True

#Import the data from yfinance. What Ticker, what period of time we want
AAPL = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
history = AAPL.history(period = "5y")
#Extract only the close data
Close = history["Close"]



#Set up a recurrence to add a column in our dataframe for the logarithmic returns of the stock
#Log returns are calculated as log_2(Close(day x)/Close(day x-1))  

logreturn = []
for i in range(len(Close)):
    if i == 0:
        logreturn.append(0) 
    else:
        x = np.log2(abs(Close[i]))-np.log2(abs(Close[i-1]))
        logreturn.append(x)
#Now we have an array with the logarithmic returns, we add it to the pandas dataframe
history["logreturn"] = logreturn
#We then pull it out for ease of use
lreturn = history["logreturn"]

if plot_lreturns == True:
    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(lreturn, color = "dodgerblue")  


#We plot the data in a histogram, by 
if plot_lreturnshist == True:
    mu, std = norm.fit(lreturn)
    plt.hist(lreturn, bins=50, density=True, alpha=0.6, color='g', ec = 'black')
    
    xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
    x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
    p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
    plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
    title = r"Fit results: $\mu$ = $%.2f$,  $\sigma$ = $%.2f$" % (mu, std)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(r"$\ln(Y_{t+1}/Y_t$)")

    plt.show()

mu, std = norm.fit(lreturn)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
S = np.sum(-p*np.log(p))
print("S")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made an entropy indicator based on a moving volume histogram as proba input and i get negative values too. In thermodynamics, negative entropy means you gain heat so  maybe it means that the market activity increase but it doesn't tell you in which direction.

You can find my indicator attempt in my [lib of indicators @ github](https://github.com/RomFR57/fastfinance). It's simply called "entropy"

Edit : Based on your comment, i have modified my entropy function and now it gives positive values

```
def entropy(c_close, c_volume, period, bins=2):
    size = len(c_close)
    out = np.array([np.nan] * size)
    # ROLLING WINDOW
    for i in range(period - 1, size):
        e = i + 1
        s = e - period
        close_w = c_close[s:e]
        volume_w = c_volume[s:e]
        # HISTO BASED ON CLOSE / VOLUME
        min_w = np.min(close_w)
        norm = 1.0 / (np.max(close_w) - min_w)
        sum_h = np.array([0.0] * bins)
        for j in range(period):
            sum_h[int((close_w[j] - min_w) * bins * norm)] += volume_w[j] ** 2
        count = np.sqrt(sum_h)
        # NORMALIZE HISTO COUNT (CONVERT TO PROBA)
        count = count / sum(count)
        # DELETE PROBAS = 0 TO AVOID GAPS
        count = count[np.nonzero(count)]
        # ENTROPY 
        out[i] = -sum(count * np.log2(count))
     return out
```